# How do I make logback read a properties file which name is a variable?

Tags: java, logging, logback

I am using http://logback.qos.ch/

I am running my java process with a parameter for example `-Dproperties.url=myappproperties-production.properties` or `-Dproperties.url=myappproperties-development.properties` depending on the environemnt it is run in.

Problem: how to make logback pick up my properties file?

If the properties file name is static I would do (**works fine**):

```
<configuration>
    <property resource="myappproperties-development.properties" />
    (...)
</configuration>
```

But I need something that is dynamic (**this does not work**):

```
<configuration>
    <property resource="${properties.url}" />
    (...)
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The value of the resource file can be a property itself. In other words,

```
<configuration debug="true">
    <property resource="${properties.url}" />
    (...)
</configuration>
```

should work. BYW, set the `debug` attribute of `<configuration>` element to `true` to see logback's internal messages on the console. Which version of logback are you using?

Comment: The problem was that `<property resource="..." />` and `<property file="..."/>` cannot handle URLs for example `file:///path/to/my.properties`. They just can handle paths to files. I raised an issue [http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-711](http://jira.qos.ch/browse/LOGBACK-711).

Comment: indeed it works - failed for me at first but I must have had a typo. Importantly for me, it works even if the filename property is loaded from a property file. But the real reason I'm +1ing this is the debug setting. That's a pro-tip I wish I knew yesterday!!

Comment: Did not work for me, instead this worked perfectly, recommended by Spring docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html

Answer (score 0):

How would you handle this if the properties url value was in inverted commas?
e.g.

```
-Dproperties.url="myappproperties-production.properties"
```

I just tried this and it didnt work

The reason I ask is because the latest version of the Amazon AMI in Amazon Elastic Beanstalk adds inverted commas around a property value - even if a user doesnt specify this

Answer (score 0):

This is the Spring recommended way:

```
<configuration>

    <springProfile name="local">
        <!-- configuration to be enabled when the "local" profile is active -->
        <property resource="application-local.properties" />
    </springProfile>

    <springProfile name="dev">
        <!-- configuration to be enabled when the "dev" profile is active -->
        <property resource="application-dev.properties" />
    </springProfile>

</configuration>
```

Reference docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html